# Can I use popen() without calling the shell? in C++

Tags: c++, linux, shell, popen

I want to call an rpm command with flags, from my C++ code and get the output, but I don't want to use shell in the process.

I think about using popen, but saw it uses shell to execute command which I don't want.
I can use the pipe\fork\exec long method, but I want to read line by line and not sure how to do it with it, so I thought of using popen() instead if it's possible to exec with it without a middle shell.

My question is if there is a way to use popen() without it calling the shell and just invoke the binary provided itself with it's flag (for example /usr/bin/rpm -qa)?
or I will have to go with the long route?

Comment: `popen` is defined (as if) in terms of a call to the shell, so there is simply no way around this. If you do not want the shell you need to perform the individual steps of `popen` (minus the shell invocation) manually.

Comment: If you want to read line by line from a file descriptor, use `fdopen` to get a FILE *.  (Although that is a C solution; C++ probably has a more idiomatic way to do the same thing.)

Comment: If you're open to using third-party libraries you might want to have a look at [boost.process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only two options here are, indeed, either to use `popen`, or `pipe`+`fork`+`exec`. These are the only options on Linux for running a program and capturing its output. That's it, there are no other possibilities. All system and C library calls on Linux have publicly available documentation, and there's nothing else.

It's theoretically possible for a `popen` implementation to parse the command and determine whether it contains any shell wildcards or special characters; if not then split it into words and `exec` the resulting program. Whether or not `popen` does that can be determined by running a simple test for this under `strace` with the `-f` flag, and seeing what actually gets executed by the spawned child process.

But even if you discover, yourself, that your current glibc does this, this not a guarantee, of course, that it will always work this way in the future.